# How do I avoid nesting promises in firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

```
'use strict'


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite((data, context) => {
        const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
        const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;


        console.log('We have a notification to send to :', receiver_user_id);


        if (!data.after.val()) {
            console.log('A notification has been deleted :', notification_id);
            return null;
        }

        const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

        return DeviceToken.then(result => {
            const token_id = result.val();

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "New Friend Request",
                    body: `You have a new friend request, please check.`,
                    icon: "default"
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload) <= Warning: Avoid nesting promises.
                .then(response => { <= Error: Each then() should return a value or throw a promise.
                    console.log('This was a notification feature.');
                });
        });
    });
```

This function is a notification function for a firebase chatapp (uMe) but when I tried to upload it in firebase an error occured (I attached it in the line of code above). how can I write it so that it could avoid those errors?

Comment: What is the error

Comment: return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload) <= Warning: Avoid nesting promises.
.then(response => { <= Error: Each then() should return a value or throw a promise.